# How can I add more attack to my Wood Bond Oracle?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

I am trying to build an oracle, and need some help with what I have so far. I'm still somewhat new to tabletop games, so any insight you have would be helpful. Here's what I have so far:

Race: Human
Class: Oracle
Mystery: Wood
Curse: Haunted

Stats are:
STR: 10
DEX: 12
CON: 14
INT: 14
WIS: 13
CHA: 19 (after +2 racial bonus)

I've chosen Wood Bond as my first revelation, as I plan on using a quarterstaff as a weapon. This is where I'm stumped (no pun intended). I liked the idea of this particular mystery/curse as it provides some really good backstory and role playing opportunities for this particular campaign, but it seems like this build doesn't really have much in the way of attack.

**How can I increase the attack of my Oracle?** I don't know if I should switch around stats, revelation, or even my mystery.

Like I said, I'm still quite new to this. So any feedback would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your main hindrance here is the 10 STR.  By having all your stats higher than your STR you're saying that melee is the least important thing about your character.  And if you're dumping melee, trying to get it back up again via other routes is worse than pointless - decide what you want to concentrate in; many successful oracles focus on the magic and can't hit the broad side of a barn.  All characters are about equal when you might need to melee (levels 1-2) and then you could concentrate on the spooky stuff safely. If you really want to melee, then you'll want to rebuild. An oracle doesn't really need that high a INT or WIS (or CON or DEX really).  Scavenge those to get at least - at *least* - 14 STR; that +2 will do more than most other stuff long term.  Ta da, +2 to hit and damage that applies to all weapons and stacks with everything.

Then you can take Weapon Focus in your staff, and/or Extra Revelation to get another combat type power.  You can also use spells like Divine Favor to bump up your fight too.

If you really want a boost, you can mix in a level of fighter or whatnot as you level. If you planned to do that you might try for some two-weapon fighting feats to make use of the double weapon nature of the staff (if not, forget it; you'll never have enough feats as an oracle to try that).

Answer (score 3):

While most Oracle builds aren't really battle oriented (with the notable exception of Battle oracles, of course), you can build a rather nice fighter with [Wood](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/wood) oracle. *Wood Bond* with a quarterstaff and the 2nd lv. bonus spell *Shillelagh* gives you pretty good attack, while *Wooden Armor* stacks with the 4th lv. bonus spell *Barkskin* for decent AC. Add *Thorn Burst* for an extra added melee kick and maybe *Improved Trip* or *Two Weapon Fighting* to make the quarterstaff extra useful.

One last thing though, I'm not sure 13 WIS is essential, since nearly all your powers are based on CHA. Consider putting it into STR, where using the quarterstaff two-handed will translate into a 1-and-a-half STR bonus, though I'm not sure what the rules are for multiplying 1 by 1.5 (round up to 2? Down to 1?

Comment: Round down, so no effective multiplication in that case.

Comment: Intelligence could be scraped too to add to strength, if your DM allows such things. Beautiful/willful people don't have to be smart all the time.